# Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' Problem Dart & flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this variables problem 
this is my `getdata` function

```
Future <List <Deal>> getData() async{


String myUrl = "http://10.25.20.27:5000/api/all";
var response = await http.get(myUrl,
    headers: {
      'Accept':'application/json',

    });

var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);

List<Deal> deals =[];

var u;

for( u in jsonData){

  Deal deal = Deal(u["id"],u["name"],u["adress"],u["photo"],u["Description"],u["discount"]);

}


return deals;
}
```

And I got this error

> Performing hot reload...
>   Reloaded 14 of 594 libraries in 902ms.
>   E/flutter ( 4211): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
>   E/flutter ( 4211): #0      DatabaseHelper.getData (package:flutter_app/databasehelper.dart:116:25)
>   E/flutter ( 4211): 
>   E/flutter ( 4211): #1      _HomeePageState.build. (package:flutter_app/homee_page.dart:100:80)
>   E/flutter ( 4211): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:654:14)
>   E/flutter ( 4211): #3      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:729:32)
>   E/flutter ( 4211): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
>   E/flutter ( 4211): #5      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
>   E/flutter ( 4211): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:275:7)
>   E/flutter ( 4211): #7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:455:9)

Comment: try printing `u` variable to see whats inside: `print(u);`

Comment: Can you share response JSON and Deal class for best to understand issue?

Comment: when i print u i get null   and thisi the `response.body` [[{id: 1, name: adresse Marrakech, adress: guéliz, photo: , Description: C'est un endroit zwiiin, discount: 30 }, {id: 2, name: Bogato, adress: guéliz, photo: , Descri
ption: bniiinnn, discount: Offres }]]

Comment: so you mean that `u` is null inside `for( u in jsonData){` loop?

Comment: this is the whole loop :   for( u in jsonData){

      Deal deal = Deal(u["id"],u["name"],u["adress"],u["photo"],u["Description"],u["discount"]);


     deals.add(deal);

    }

Comment: so add `print('u: >$u<');` before `Deal deal = ...`, what do you see in the logs?

Comment: this is the result : >[{id: 1, name: adresse Marrakech, adress: guéliz, photo: , Description: C'est un endroit zwiiin, discount: 30 }, {id: 2, name: Bogato, adress: guéliz, photo: , Des
cription: bniiinnn, discount: Offres }]<

Comment: so as you can see you nave an array of maps - because the first character is `[` meaning its an array and the elements of that array is a map because the next character is `{` - so in order to get the map you have to access it via `u[0]`, `u[1]` etc

Comment: when i modified my code like this : `  var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    //print (jsonData);
    List<Deal> deals =[];

    var u;
   // print (u);

    for( u in jsonData){
    // print('u: >$u<');
      Deal deal = Deal(u[0],u[1],u[2],u[3],u[4],u[5]);


     deals.add(deal);

    }` i got this error : **Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int'
**

Comment: `var v = u[0]; Deal deal = Deal(v["id"],v["name"],v["adress"],v["photo"],v["Description"],v["discount"]);`

Comment: but now i can get just the first result i need another loop to get all the info

Comment: this is what i told you in the previous comment: `"so as you can see you nave an array of maps"` - so for example you can simply use: `u.forEach((v) { Deal deal = Deal(v["id"],v["name"],v["adress"],v["photo"],v["Description"],v["discount"]); // do something with deal })`

Comment: yes exactly this is what i did ! thank u so much for ur help

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create "Deal" class like below:-

```
class Deal {
  String id;
  String name;
  String adress;
  String photo;
  String Description;
  String discount;

  Deal(
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.adress,
    this.photo,
    this.Description,
    this.discount,
  );
}
```

Then you can use loop like below :-

```
var u;
for (u in jsonData) {
      Deal deal = Deal(
          u["id"].toString(),
          u["name"].toString(),
          u["adress"].toString(),
          u["photo"].toString(),
          u["Description"].toString(),
          u["discount"].toString());
}
```